# simplecov gem code coverage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-coverage, minitest

i use minitest framework for testing and simplecov gem for code coverage. i have a problem about simplecov. my problem is lkie this:

i wrote a model test. when i run the test using **rake minitest:models**, test runs and coverage shows %100. But when i run tests using **bundle exec rake**, the code coverage of same tests are shown missing.

i make researching on net. some people also have problem like this about simplecov. but i could not find a solution for this.
i'm waiting your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did you enabled `simplecov` by doing `SimpleCov.start` on top of your code?

This is required as the first statement i.e. before your code, otherwise you will never get it work.

Also include the [SimpleCoV Adapter](https://github.com/michaeledgar/simplecov-gem-adapter).

As following the post [generating-code-coverage-metrics-for-a-ruby-on-rails-project-with-simplecov](http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/tools-plugins/generating-code-coverage-metrics-for-a-ruby-on-rails-project-with-simplecov/), define rules with SimpleCov putting conditions:

```
SimpleCov.start do
  # rules here
end if ENV["COVERAGE"]
```

Then run the coverage on demand by specifying the coverage variable:

```
COVERAGE=true bundle exec rake spec
```

Comment: yes. i made it. it runs already but results are not shown %100, if i use bundle exec rake. For example, if i run using rake minitest:models, coverage is shown %100.